# windows/global object library don't work with webpack5

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I coded my library which add Class to global window object:

```
const Maplat = window.Maplat = {};

Maplat.createObject = blah blah..
```

With being compiled by webpack4, this works very well.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./assets/maplat_core.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      Maplat.createObject(...);
      // Works fine
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But after I updated webpack 5, this does not work.

I checked the compiled result code, it is comiled as:

```
          ...
          , Tv = window.Maplat = {};
        Tv.createObject = function(t) {
            return new Promise((function(e) {
                var n = new Rv(t);
                n.waitReady.then((function() {
                    e(n)
                }
                ))
            }
            ))
        }
    }
    )()
}
)();
```

With this compiled result,

```
const Maplat = window.Maplat = {};
```

works after

```
Maplat.createObject(...);
```

so this compiled result does not work.

How to resolve this?
How can I add class to window/global object by webpack5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it became work with this webpack setting:

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dev"),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
```